# How can I reduce the time-taken by Microsoft Word while saving a large document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using MS Word 2013. I have a document (docx file) that's 400+ pages. It's a log of some sort that I need to keep updating daily. After every few lines I have a habit of doing a ctrl+S (save) which takes a very long time (about 30 - 60  seconds). The document has no images and only text.

What can I do to speed up the save times?

Comment: Don't, seriously, don't. Break it down into individual months, weeks or days. If it gets corrupted, then the whole document could be ruined.

Comment: If the document is being saved onto an HDD, then upgrading that to an SSD would likely make the saving very much faster (and the whole computer in general).

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm already on an SSD. It's still slow.

Comment: If it is a log, then most likely formatting is not that important. Besides splitting the file into smaller chunks I would consider switching to a plain text format you can edit with any editor. If you need some formatting you could use Markdown syntax.

Comment: @Bib I like your idea. I'll switch to using yearly docs. I haven't ever witnessed a doc getting corrupted. I think that might be an Internet transport corruption and not in the harddisk?

Answer (score 1):

### Make sure that all of your formatting is done using Styles with no manual page breaks.

Here is [my writing on this](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Overview).

> For long documents, documents that are likely to be heavily edited, and
> documents that may form the basis for other documents, follow the
> basic rule that to change formatting use Styles... Do not
> apply direct formatting.
>
> In Ribbon versions of Word (2007+) this is even easier, click on your
> style from the Styles gallery!
>
> You will save yourself, and others, untold hours of hair-tearing. For
> shorter one-use documents, direct formatting is OK; you'll only regret
> not using styles about one time in six, on the other five out of the
> six, you'll save a bit of time. If you create document templates with
> direct formatting, you deserve what will happen to you when someone
> finds out (and it won't be nice). In my opinion, using direct
> formatting in document templates intended for use by others rates the
> words malicious and/or incompetent. If the templates are for your own
> use, you deserve the loss of days, months, even years from your life
> that you'll spend fighting with Word and trying to figure out why your
> documents look so bad.
>
> Trying to use Word without understanding and using styles is like
> pushing on a string. I resisted learning and using styles for years
> and now regret every day of those years because although that string
> was still very hard to push, it kept getting longer and longer, and
> had some very important projects tied to it! Once you understand
> styles and the Word concept of organizing things into Chinese boxes
> everything falls into place and instead of pushing a string, you can
> push a button that turns on the very powerful text processing machine
> known as Microsoft Word and it will start doing your work for you
> instead of running around behind you trying to undo what you thought
> you just did.
>
> These statements should be even stronger for those using Word 2007-19
> because styles are even easier to use in the ribbon versions of Word.
>
> I just had occasion to edit a 100-page document that was created
> without using styles. It was formatted completely with direct
> formatting. Each page ended with a page break.
>
> Each time it had to be saved, the save took more than 60 seconds,
> during which time Word was frozen.
>
> A similar-sized document formatted using Styles takes less than 3
> seconds for me to save. When a page break must be forced, instead of
> using a manual page break, the paragraph to begin the new page is
> formatted using a style that has "page break before" paragraph
> formatting.
>
> This difference was due entirely to the document being directly
> formatted - a much higher level of complexity. Each paragraph mark in
> a directly-formatted paragraph carries with it up to fifty different
> formatting commands. When formatted using a style, that paragraph mark
> will carry with it one command - use this style!
>
> --CKK 1 Feb 2012

> See an [example of a document formatted using styles](http://www.addbalance.com/word/download.htm#SampleStyles) for two virtually
> identical documents, one formatted using Styles, the other mostly not
> using Styles. Both have the same number of words and pages. One is
> 34K; the other is 48K.
>
> --CKK 6 Jan 2016
>
> In this [Word Forum thread](https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/43721-computer-slow-5-files.html), the poster was having a very sluggish
> response from Word. I advised changing formatting from direct
> formatting to style-based. Problem solved!
>
> --CKK 30 Oct 2019
>
> See also: [Yet Another "Use Styles" Verbal Beating!](http://web.archive.org/web/20130801153111/http://pubs.logicalexpressions.com/Pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=232) by Dian
> Chapman, MVP

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this but I cannot go through 400+ pages figuring out styles used everywhere and editing everything.

Comment: The point is that there are not styles used everywhere. Chances are very high that the document is all formatted using the normal style and direct formatting applied to change the appearance. The enter key was likely used to control inter-paragraph spacing and manual page breaks interjected at will. Someone used typewriter methods with Word. https://shaunakelly.com/word/concepts/introduction.html

Comment: I would create a new document. Paste the content from the original as plain text,  Eliminate double paragraph marks and manual page breaks. Then format it using styles. It may take a few hours, yes. It can be done.

Comment: +1 I'm not willing to do this for my document because I definitely need the formatting because there's some color coding as well in the text which is very important. But perhaps this helps others who are okay to lose all their formatting. Honestly, if we're removing all formatting it beats the whole point of using MS Word. I might as well just use Notepad++ or something of the sort. So it will no longer remain a word document.

Comment: What I am proposing, and I have done in the past, is to add the formatting back into the new document, using styles.